# convert 128 bit to array of 8 bit c#

Tags: c#

I have a decimal value consisting of 128 bit (16 bytes).
I want to convert it to array of 8 bits, such as

```
decimal a='1234567890123456'// 128 bit.  
int [] k =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

Can you help me with a code in C# language?

Can I declare int 128 bit rather than decimal value in C#?

I've tried this code but I'm searching for another way

```
subk[i] = decimal.ToInt32(key);
SubKeys.Items.Add(subk[i]);
```

Comment: Clarify your question, it's unclear what you are asking here...

Comment: thanks for your reply.  actually i  have 128 bit value and i want to convert it to array of 16 elements,8 bit for each,such as  a=1234567890123456 i want to convert it to b[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use LINQ to solve the issue:

```
decimal a = 1234567890123456;// 128 bit.
int[] k = a.ToString().Select(digit => int.Parse(digit.ToString())).ToArray();
```

Comment: thanks,can you explain this code for me ?

Comment: It's ultimately converts your decimal to string, splits it into individual numbers and adds it to an int[]

Comment: thanks , i have tried it and it works correctly :) .

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it, but perhaps the easiest (but not necessarily the most efficient) is to convert it to string and then take one character at a time in a loop:

```
decimal a=1234567890123456;
string b=a.ToString();
List<int> array = new List<int>();
foreach(char c in b){
    array.Add(int.Parse(c.ToString()));
}
```